# php extract value from array and pass to function as arguments

Tags: php, arrays, extract

How can I extract `[p_id]` value and pass as arguments in a function?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [p_name] => X-Dot Motorbike Helmet
            [p_id] => 1001
            [p_price] =>  1.60
            [p_alt-variation-1] => Red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [p_name] => Salt and Lemon Candy
            [p_id] => 1002
            [p_price] => 1.20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [p_name] => Romoss Rolink Hybrid Cable
            [p_id] => 1003
            [p_price] => 13.90
        )

)
```

for example, I need these id's pass into a function for SQL statement:

```
function process($ids = array('1001','1002','1003')) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pid IN('1001','1002','1003') GROUP BY categoryId";

    ...

}
```

Comment: `process(array_column($yourArray, 'p_id'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `$array` is your two-dimentional array, loop over it and add all the IDs to another array, and pass that as an argument

```
$ids = array(); // Declare array which will contain IDs
foreach ($array as $value) {
    // Loop over array, and get the IDs, put it into your $ids array
    $ids[] = $value['p_id'];
}

// Pass it as an argument
process($ids);
```

Then you'll need to adapt your query, as it's currently static. Use `implode()` to make an array into a string, like this

```
function process($ids = array() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pid IN('".implode("', '", $ids)."') GROUP BY categoryId";

    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how to add single quote for these implode id?

Comment: I updated my answer with quotes around the strings. Simply put, you add quotes before and after the `implode()`, and then use it as part of the "glue" as it's called.

Comment: If the IDs are integers though, shouldn't need quotes around them. Only if they are strings. Better yet though, just use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

use array_map() to get all the ids into $ids array:

```
   $ids = array_map(function($v){return $v[p_id];}, $array);
```

then you can pass the $ids array as a parameter of you function.

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_column` and `implode` functions:

```
// $data is your initial array
$ids = array_column($data, 'p_id');

function process($ids = []) {
    if (!empty($ids)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pid IN(".implode(", ", $ids).") GROUP BY categoryId";
    } 

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly extract out value from p_id by using `array_column` (ie: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

   ```
   $value = array_column($array, 'p_id');
   ```
2. then u can pass the $value into your function

   ```
   process($value);
   ```
3. you implode your array inside your function before passing it into your sql

   ```
   function process($value = array()) {
       $value = "'".implode("', '", $value)."'";
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE pid IN({$value}) GROUP BY categoryId";
   }
   ```